# Cant populate wampserver database from website form?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

Whenever i complete a form within my website and the submit button is pressed, it is not pushing the data from here into the wampserver/phpmyadmin database that i have created?

It is my first time doing this, I think it is almost working as it isnt giving me any errors whilst running. But I cannot pin point where I am going wrong, and i'm guessing its something easy which i am overlooking

This is the php code:

```
<?php
function renderform($firstname, $lastname, $emailaddress, $contactnumber, $query, $error)
{
    ?><?php
    // connect to the database
    include('connect.php');
    // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        // get form data, making sure it is valid
        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($_POST['FirstName']));
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($_POST['LastName']));
        $emailaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($_POST['EmailAddress']));
        $contactnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($_POST['ContactNumber']));
        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, htmlspecialchars($_POST['Query']));
        // check to make sure both fields are entered
        if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '' || $emailaddress == '' || $contactnumber == '' || $query == '') {
            // generate error message
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
            // if either field is blank, display the form again
            renderform($firstname, $lastname, $emailaddress, $contactnumber, $query, $error);
        } else {
            // save the data to the database
            $query = ("INSERT INTO contact SET FirstName='$firstname', LastName='$lastname', EmailAddress='$emailaddress', ContactNumber='$contactnumber', Query='$query' ");
            $data = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
            // once saved, redirect back to the view page
            header("Location: contact.php");
        }
    } else {// if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
            renderForm('', '', '', '', '', '');
    }
}

?>
```

The collected results should be displayed into wampserver/phpmyadmin database which i will eventually put into a cloud host..

Comment: Does `SET` works for a `INSERT INTO` statement ? if not try with `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);`

Comment: You have a variety of `if` statements there, how have you confirmed that the logic is following the path you expect?  If you can use a debugger that would be ideal, but failing that one simple approach is to add a variety of `echo` statements in your code to indicate the overall flow of the logic.  For all we know `if (isset($_POST['Submit']))` could be `false`, and the code is working as designed.

Comment: Yes it does, @Frankich. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: do you really have  button with `Submit` name attribute or it's `submit` with lowercase?

Comment: thanks for replies, @David i will try your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile changed all to lower case still no results, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your variables are not empty, you can pass the values using parameters as such:

```
$query = $this->dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO contact SET FirstName=?, LastName=?, EmailAddress=?, ContactNumber=?");
$query->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $contact_no);
$query->execute();
```

Make sure you can echo your variables to ensure your form is submitting the values.

Comment: `- >`  (with a space) would throw syntax errors. I'm editing your answer to better format it.

Comment: tried this earlier, couldnt get it working but will give it another go tomorrow